# Shorthand to deep object literal?

Tags: javascript, object

I am working with a slider builder that has about 10 levels of objects and arrays to store all the data.. The first 4 are pretty much always structured the same, but are in different arrays. For example:

```
Slides[thisSlide].layers[thisLayer].animationgroup[thisAnimationId].sequence[currentSegment].duration
```

where at any given time I am probably working on the same slide, the same layer, so I was thinking I could declare some variables such as:

```
var currentSlide = 0;
var currentLayer = 0;
var currentChild = "0";
var currentKeyframe = "";
    Slides.push({
    "background-color": "#aaaaaa",
    "canvasHeight": "200",
    "canvasWidth": "1000",
    "layers": []
    });
var CSL = Slides[currentSlide].layers[currentLayer];
var CAG = Slides[thisSlide].layers[thisLayer].animationgroup[thisAnimationId];
```

at the beginning of the application which could then be used to shorthand the first example in this way:

```
CAG.sequence[currentSegment].duration;
```

It didn't work as I expected it to. later when I tried using it, I get a complaint that CSL isn't defined, and yet it should be in the global scope:

```
function updateStuff(){
    for (i = 0; i < CSL.length; i++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I am just trying to shorten my code a little as I work on it and eliminate things that don't really need to be there.

Comment: Assuming object exists at all those layers, I dont see any issue with notation you posted. You should be able to work with those shorthand

Comment: This should work, until you are Not having a *closure* on the variable which are used as indexes in the statements.

Comment: That was what I was thinking too, I updated it to show where I am having an issue.

Comment: CSL seems like is pointing to object inside an array which do not have length. Is that what your issue is?

Comment: What I included was just the variable declaration, after initialization, there is info in that array. It works fine if I put the variable declaration inside the function, but for some reason it doesn't like it in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

In your example here:

```
var currentSlide = 0;
var currentLayer = 0;
var currentChild = "0";
var currentKeyframe = "";
    Slides.push({
    "background-color": "#aaaaaa",
    "canvasHeight": "200",
    "canvasWidth": "1000",
    "layers": []
    });
var CSL = Slides[currentSlide].layers[currentLayer];
```

It looks like the `layers` array is empty, so indexing into the `layers` array will return undefined to `CSL` in this case.

Note that if there is an object defined at that time, you will indeed get a reference to that object, but if nothing is defined then `CSL` is assigned the "value type" `undefined` with no reference.

Comment: I think this may have to do with an order of operations. It may try loading all the variables into memory before pushing the info into the Slides object. When it does it that way, there isn't anything at all in the Slides[0] object and so it fails. I am looking at how to work around the issue by updating it later upon user interaction.